# Data is not being fetched in react.js app when I host it on GCP/Heroku/Netlify

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, fetch, omdbapi

I'm trying to fetch some movie data by title from OMDB. It works just fine on my machine but when I host it on providers such as GCP/Heroku/Netlify my search don't return anything. Here is the link to the GCP hosted site: https://joypaultheshoppies1234.web.app and here is the repo with codes: https://github.com/cosmicRover/the_shoppies you can see in the gif that the searches are supposed to return some items as JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing with the error message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://joypaultheshoppies1234.web.app/' was loaded 
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=T&apikey=[your_api_key]'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Your browser is blocking the fetch from https://joypaultheshoppies1234.web.app/ because you're making a request from a secure site (`https`) to a non secure endpoint (`http`). It's *not* failing on your local machine because (I'm assuming) your locally running site is not secured.

**Solution:**
Change the URL (protocol) string in your application to the endpoint from `http` to `https`. (`https` is supported by that OMDB endpoint.)

For example: [https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Top+Gun&apikey=[your_api_key]](https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Top+Gun&apikey=%5Byour_api_key%5D)

[MDN on Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

> **Mixed content**
> When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their
> connection with the web server is encrypted with TLS and is therefore
> safeguarded from most sniffers and man-in-the-middle attacks. An HTTPS
> page that includes content fetched using cleartext HTTP is called a
> mixed content page. Pages like this are only partially encrypted,
> leaving the unencrypted content accessible to sniffers and
> man-in-the-middle attackers. That leaves the pages unsafe.